# How to write a SQL query to generate a report in mysql

Tags: mysql

I need to generate a report like the below table

```
Collection       |Model|Units Sold|Price USD |Price Euro|Price gbp
-----------------+-----+----------+----------+----------+----------
Pays de la Loire | 1301|         2|      1000|        600|      400
Toscana          | 1301|         1|       500|        300|      200
Provence         | 1302|         1|       400|        400|      400
```

Below are the 3 tables from where this above i need to generate

order Table

```
ID|collection_fk|model_fk
--+-----------+---------
 1|          1|        1
 2|          1|        1
 3|          2|        1
 4|          3|        2
```

Collection Table

```
ID|Collection
--+-----------
 1| Pays de la Loire
 2| Toscana
 3| Provence
 4|  Lorraine
```

Models Table

```
ID|model_no   |collection_fk|price_usd|price_euro|price_gbp
--+-----------+-------------+---------+----------+---------
 1|       1301|            1|     500|        300|      200
 2|       1302|            1|     400|        400|      400
 3|       1303|            2|     300|        200|      500
 4|       1304|            3|     200|        100|      300
```

How would i write a query to get sum of same collection and models and count number of units sold an count their price accordingly.

Comment: the first section is the result that i need from the below 3 table  order Table,Collection Table,Models Table.

Comment: Do you have any code that you have tried? No offense, because I'm rather new here as well, but I think questions are supposed to include code that you have already tried. The way you phrased your question, just seems like you'd like it coded for you. Which I started doing, but then realized that you have no code :-)

Comment: @user3380012 are you sure the posted sum of price is correct ? i guess usd price for model 1301 should be 1000 for 2 units

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid yes sorry for my mistake you are right for moel 1301 price will be 100 usd price

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use joins with some aggregation

```
select 
c.Collection,
m.model_no,
count(o.ID) units_sold,
sum(m.price_usd),
sum(m.price_euro),
sum(m.price_gbp)
from model m
join `order` o on m.ID = o.model_fk
join collection c on c.ID = o.collection_fk
group by c.Collection,m.model_no
order by m.model_no
```

[`DEMO`](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/096c1/2)